# Troubles with Shared Object linking and Fpic

Tags: c, linux, shared-objects

I'm writing some c code for a class and am having issues with the compiler which needs to be done in a make file, when it is run it always gives the error

`usr/bin/ld: main.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol "integrand" can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: integration.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against ".rodata" can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`

I've attempted to change the makefile in multiple ways to fix this error on the linux system but alas its still to no avail.

```
all: main.o integration.o libintegration.so
    gcc -fPIC main.o integration.o libintegration.so -o target_bin
libintegration.so: main.o integration.o
    gcc main.o integration.o -shared -o libintegration.so
main.o: main.c integration.h
    gcc -I . -c main.c
integration.o: integration.c integration.h
    gcc -I . -c integration.c
clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.so
    rm target_bin
```

Thank you for any help that you can provide

Comment: I think you need to complied main.c and integration.c with fpic.

Comment: Thanks man, it makes sense to me now that that's why it was not working

Answer (score 0):

Compile main.c and integration.c with fpic.